# Copy info from DHCP to Manual settings in Network Manager?

Tags: networking, kubuntu, network-manager, dhcp

What I want to achieve is to get all info from DHCP (DNS servers, search domains, IP) as the starting point for my manual settings.

Example: what I do right now is to set is as Automatic and then run `nmcli`, from there I try to figure out what I need to put in the manual settings but it's slow and cumbersome.

I would prefer to do this via the UI but if it needs to be done via nmcli I think that's fine too.

This is because I usually need everything as it comes from DHCP but I need to set an static IP.

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: I recommend that you use a static IP address *outside* of the DHCP pool in the router.